# Showing $\sum_{m=1}^{q-1}m^{(q+1)/2}\equiv0\bmod{q}$, where $q$ is an odd prime congruent to $3 \bmod{4}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I'm reading through Davenport's "Multiplicative Number Theory", and came across this expression on page 53.
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{q-1} m^{(q+1)/2} \equiv 0 \mod q,
$$
where $q$ is an odd prime congruent to $3\bmod 4$.

In the book, this is stated as if it should be immediately clear, but for some reason, I just can't see it. Can anyone help with my tunnel vision?

Comment: Hint: $q-m \equiv -m \mod q$

Comment: @Desperado, I'm not sure I follow. Replacing $m$ with $q-m$ in the sum just reduces to the original sum once you expand via the binomial theorem and remove terms divisible by $q$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $q\equiv 1 \pmod 4$?  I mean, the claim is true for all odd $q>3$ but it is easier to prove if $q\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @lulu, I am pretty sure. You're right that the $1\mod 4 $ case is much easier. I think this is what Desperado was hinting at.

Comment: I agree.  In any case, I posted a general solution for $q>3$ below.  It is worth noting that the claim is false for $q=3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $q>3$, but there is no need to set a value for $q\pmod 4$.  We remark that the claim is false for $q=3$.

Let $t$ be a non-zero residue $\pmod q$ such that $t^{(q+1)/2}\not \equiv 1 \pmod q$.  Such a $t$ exists since the order of any $t$ for which $t^{(q+1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod q$ would have to be a divisor of $\gcd(q-1, \frac {q+1}2)≤2$ and, since $q>3$, we can avoid such $t$.

Now, multiplying the list of residues by $t$ just permutes them.  It follows that $$\sum m^{(q+1)/2}\equiv t^{(q+1)/2}\sum m^{(q+1)/2}\implies \sum m^{(q+1)/2}\equiv 0 \pmod q$$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you! Is $t$ supposed to be $n$ in your last equation?

Comment: Oh, yes.  I changed $n$ to $t$  half way through for absolutely no reason.  Thanks.  I will edit to correct.  I will change all the $n's$ to $t's$.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks again.

Comment: Just want to add that this same proof will work to establish that for $q-1 \nmid a$, $\sum m^a \equiv 0 \pmod q$. (You also might need to know that $(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ is a cyclic group).

Answer (score 1):

In the case $q \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ we have that $q-1$ and $\frac{q+1}{2}$ are coprime so raising numbers to the $\frac{q+1}{2}$ power induces a bijection on the unit group.

If $q \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ this is not necessarily true since you get the sum of the quadratic residues (take $q = 3$).

More generally, you could write this as a geometric series by considering a generator of the unit group.